# Angular service/value is not picking up new var from $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, document-ready, angular-services

I have an Angular service/value that is attempting to pick up a variable, but it picks up the original instead of the new one. The new variable should be the one inside $(document).ready() as seen below:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
var db = "asdf"
$(document).ready(function(){
    // document.getElementById("DB_content").value === '[{"name":"Joe", "age":"19"}, {"name":"Jill", "age":"21"}]'
    db = document.getElementById("DB_content").value;
    console.log(db);
});
app.value("DBcontent", db);
```

But instead of DBcontent holding the string "array", it is holding "asdf". I suspect it is because app.value("DBcontent", db) is being executed immediately, even before $(document).ready(). I have tried putting var db outside of $(document).ready() but that breaks it. Does anyone know what I can do here?

https://jsfiddle.net/dop49d54/4/

Comment: app.value will be assigned before ready event fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.value(...)` runs immediately, before `$(document).ready(...)`

If you want it to have the value acquired in `$(document).ready(...)` you need to move it inside that event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    // document.getElementById("DB_content").value === '[{"name":"Joe", "age":"19"}, {"name":"Jill", "age":"21"}]'
    var db = document.getElementById("DB_content").value;
    console.log(db);
    app.value("DBcontent", db);
});
```

---

Moving the `<script>` tag down to the bottom of the `<body>` will work!

```
<script>
var db = "asdf";
(function go(){
    db = document.getElementById("DB_content").value;
    console.log(db);
    app.value("DBcontent", db);
})();
<script>
```

Comment: Moving app.value(..) inside $(document).ready() will break the code and result in Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider. It seems like angular.value(..) can be instantiated from inside jQuery.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, fixing my answer.  Another line need to move as well.

Comment: * cannot be instantiated from inside jQuery <br/>
Even adding angular.module("app", [ ]) inside $(document).ready() will not work.

Comment: *Can't* be instantiated inside a jquery callback..that's annoying.  Try the self-calling function `(function(){ ... })();` instead of `.ready()`.  Either way, you need to wait for the page to be fully loaded before you can access the DB_Content element.

Comment: I tried various ways of using anonymous functions (IIFEs) but they all throw the same Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider.

Comment: @KangzeHuang Only thing I can think of then is to move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<body>` tag and dispensing with the anonymous functions entirely.  That insures that the script is loaded last and that the rest of the HTML content has been registered with the DOM.

Comment: HAHA that worked! Thanks so much mate, Ill mark your answer as correct with these changes. :)

Comment: @KangzeHuang Edits made.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you have marked the `db` variable inside the `$document.ready()` function as local by prefixing it with `var`.

The `db` variable inside the function wouldn't update your global `db` variable defined next to the angular app.

Also note that `app.value("DBcontent", db);` runs before the `$document.ready()`. If you need to feed an angular variable with something from the DOM, make the DOM element a directive and set the values in the scope. Or you can also use `ng-init` in this case.

Comment: Good catch! I fixed the var db. How would ng-init fit in this case? If you could give an example? :)